# Trying to loop through a directory and create a shapefile of a given threshold using arcpy.

Tags: arcpy, raster, shapefile, loop, conditional

Below is my code. I'm having issues with this will work sometimes then other times it will not work.

```
# Import dependencies:
import arcpy
import glob, os
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Define variables:
filepath = r'\'
folder = []
threshold = -19

os.chdir(filepath) 
for i in glob.glob('*.tif'):
    folder.append(i)    

# Loop through the folder:
ras = arcpy.Raster(i)
body = arcpy.sa.Con(ras < threshold, 1)
outfile = r'' + i[17:35] + '.shp' 
body_shp = arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(body, outfile, "NO_SIMPLIFY")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please tell us about the issues you are having with the code - you can [edit] your question to include detailed information about what happens when you run your code, and how it differs to what you expect.  Include any error messages you encounter.  Also give more details about what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Your line `filepath = r'\'` will fail.  You cannot have a single backslash `'\'` as a string variable - you need either a double backslash `'\\'` or a forward slash `'/'`.  That said, it appears there should be a path here, like `r'C:\Temp'`

Comment: Also, you have a comment `# Loop through the folder:`, but you're not looping through any folder.  You either need a new `for` loop, or indent some more lines inside your previous `for` loop.